# SSRS 2008R2 Change Column Colour Based on Percentage Parameter Value

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

SSRS MSSQL 2008 R2

Hi

I have two parameters, "TopPerformersPercent" = 15 and "WorstPerformersPercent" = 20.

I want to be able to change the cells on one column (Total) based on these values.

The colour change needs to be based on a percentage value.

The "TopPerformersPercent" cells on the "Total" column should be in Green, i.e the Top 15 percent.

The "WorstPerformersPercent" cells on the "Total" column should be in Red, i.e the Worst 20 percent in Red.

And all the cells in between should be in Amber.

Is this possible, if so how?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already calculated their "performer %" and have that available as a field in your dataset, use an expression like this for your background color for those cells:

```
=Switch(
   Fields!Total.Value <= Parameters!WorstPerformersPercent.Value, "#00ff00",
   Fields!Total.Value >= Parameters!TopPerformersPercent.Value, "#ff0000",
   true, "#ffe4B5"
)
```

Fortunately your logic is simple, so we don't need to worry about multiple-positives scenarios here.  The third line in the switch statement functions as a default, applying your amber color if neither of the first 2 conditions are met.

Comment: Thanks for this Kyzen.
I have however not, calculated their "performer %". How would you do that?

Comment: Do it in your SQL, that'll likely be easier than trying to do in the RDL.  Depending on the complexity of your calculation for a top performer, you might find it easiest to use windowing functions:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx